# I'm not able to open the steam client in Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit

Tags: steam, 16.10

I'm not able to open the steam client in Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit.
I downloaded the client the link

The deb package came, I installed everything right.
It turns out that at the time of running the executable steam it flashes, flashes on the side menu of unity and fails to open the client.

I record the problem on my youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuwBgcesLko&feature=youtu.be

how i resolve ?

Comment: You mean 16.10 (released this month, code name Yakkety Yak)?

Comment: yes
I wrote wrong.
soo fast...
16.10
not 10.16

Comment: Please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `steam` inside it. You should get some debug information on what's going wrong, please [edit] your question and add that output. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, i rsolve this with this comand 

find ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" -o -name "libgpg-error.so*" \) -print -delete

found on this
http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/350542683198244989/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with the following command

```
find ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" -o -name "libgpg-error.so*" \) -print -delete
```

found at http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/350542683198244989/.